# java : Arrange and retrieve data using HashMap and List

Tags: java, list, data-structures, hashmap

I have data like in following logical format:

```
FolderID-1
    FileID-1
    FileID-2    
FolderID-2
    FileID-3
    FileID-4
    FileID-5
    FileID-6    
FolderID-3
    FileID-7
    FileID-8
    FileID-9
    FileID-10
```

I have list of `FileID` object which have `FoldeID`
I need to update one field in this list and need to pass to this list in other method.

I need to get `FileID` object based on `fileid & folderid` in that method.
To achieve the same I know two way
`1 HashMap<folderid,List<FileID>>` OR
`2 HashMap<folderid, HashMap<fileid ,FileID>`

Is there any other efficient way to do the same?
Thanks for looking here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits your purpose, but what if you create composite `Key {folderID, fileID}` and use it as a HashMap key with corresponding File value? Just pay attention on equals and hashCode methods of Key class

Comment: In my approach there will be unique folderId and fileID
So, I am thinking to keep as key {folderID + fileID}  (sum of both id)

Comment: Yes, in case if `folderId + fileID` is unique this seems to be perfect match for the Key

Comment: "sum of both id" is not guaranteed to be unique. Folder 7 plus file 6 will be 13. Folder 8 plus file 5 is equal to 13.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for suggestion, I will use String as key which is combination of folderid and fileid

Comment: A more efficient key would be to use a long (64 bit) integer, with the folder id (32 bit integer) in the high 32 bits, and the file id (another 32 bit integer) in the low 32 bits. You can create it with something like `long key = ((long)folderId << 32) + fileId;` This assumes that you won't have more than 4 billion folders, and no folder will have more than 4 billion files.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I read your cmnt you can go ahead with the string key (using fileid and folder id) that will work for you. But your data comes with a nice logical structure . file id and folder id will be unique as well as a single folder will contain file having the file id is consecutive. So, My approach to solve this entirely depends on this structure.

I made two Class FileIdObj and FolderIdObj thats contains the data redarding the file and folder respectively.

```
public static void fileIdBasedOnFileIdAndFolderId( List<FileIdObj> fileList)
    {
        Map<Integer,FolderIdObj> folderIdMap=new HashMap<Integer,FolderIdObj>();
        Map<Integer,FileIdObj> fileIdMap=new HashMap<Integer,FileIdObj>();

        for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
        {
            FileIdObj file=fileList.get(i);
            fileIdMap.put(file.getFileId(), file);

            int folderId=file.getFolderId();
            FolderIdObj folder=new FolderIdObj();

            if(folderIdMap.containsKey(folderId))
            {
                folder=folderIdMap.get(folderId);
                folder.setEndFileId(file.getFileId());
            }else
            {
                folder.setFolderId(folderId);
                folder.setStartFileId(file.getFileId());
                folder.setEndFileId(file.getFileId());
            }

            folderIdMap.put(folderId, folder);
        }

        Set<Integer> set=folderIdMap.keySet();
        Iterator it=set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            FolderIdObj obj=folderIdMap.get(it.next());
            System.out.println("folder id: "+obj.getFolderId()+" start fileId: "+obj.getStartFileId()+
                    " end fileId: "+obj.getEndFileId());
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        set=fileIdMap.keySet();
        it=set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            FileIdObj obj=fileIdMap.get(it.next());
            System.out.println("file id: "+obj.getFileId()+" folder id:"+obj.getFolderId());
        }
    }
```

the list on the argument contains the file object only.
Please see below for the details of the two class.

```
public class FileIdObj {

    private int folderId;
    private int fileId;

    public int getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }
    public void setFolderId(int folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }
    public int getFileId() {
        return fileId;
    }
    public void setFileId(int fileId) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }

}
public class FolderIdObj {

    private int folderId;
    private int startFileId;
    private int endFileId;

    public int getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }
    public void setFolderId(int folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }
    public int getStartFileId() {
        return startFileId;
    }
    public void setStartFileId(int startFileId) {
        this.startFileId = startFileId;
    }
    public int getEndFileId() {
        return endFileId;
    }
    public void setEndFileId(int endFileId) {
        this.endFileId = endFileId;
    }

}
```